# Need a link in Email of New Task Created through Designer Workflow to redirect to the EDIT FORM of the Task

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-email

I am working with Office 365 where I have created a workflow using SharePoint Designer, which has few approvals.

The requirement here is:

- In the task creation email sent to the approver, can we provide a
  link that directly opens the edit form of the task for approver for
  approval of the task?
- There is a link in the task creation email, that redirects to the display    form of the Task but I need a link that redirects to the edit form directly.

I am even using a custom content type in the Workflow Task List for custom Task Outcome values and have created a custom edit form for the same in designer under Workflow Task List.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the link from the approval form and include it in the email being sent.

You will have to include a reference to the task-id.

Eg,

`https://host.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection/list/listname/editform.aspx?ID=[Current_Item_ID]`

For the second part, you'd just need to add:

`&source="https://host.sharepoint.com/sites/redirectsite"`

to the end of the url above to redirect another page or site.